Mermaid.js in a script file for Blazor
I have a Markdown Editor component for Blazor. In this component, I use an old version of Mermaid to display graphs.
I added the Mermaid library using this script
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>

Unfortunately, this version raises an error

e.replace is not a function

So, I tried to replace this script with
<script type="module">
    import mermaid 
        from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';
    mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true });
</script>

In this case, I don't have an error but the graph is not rendered because when I check if
if (typeof mermaid !== 'undefined') {
    // code
}

is always false. So, I tried to add the code abode in the JavaScript script like
import { mermaid } 
    from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';
mermaid.initialize({
    startOnLoad: true
});

// rest of the script

but in this case, the error is

Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'initialize' ('initialize' was undefined).
Error: Could not find 'initialize' ('initialize' was undefined).

So, my questions are:

how can I add the import in my script and call the initialize function
how can I check if mermaid is available

